# JPA entity inheritance: which instance to create for lazy initialization?

Tags: jpa, inheritance, proxy, lazy-initialization

JPA entity inheritance: which instance to create for lazy initialization? For example,

Single table mapping strategy:

```
          Teacher(abstract)
          /               \
FullTimeTeacher   PartTimeTeacher
```

Entity School referencing Teacher:

```
@Entity
public class School {
     @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
     private Teacher manager;
}
```

When retrieving a School entity from database, the school's manager is lazy, not initialized. Which type of proxy will be instantiated?  Teacher is abstract.

The proxy may not match the actual referenced type (Full Time or Part Time Teacher).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was curious myself, and tested it with the following setup:

```
@Entity
public class Garage {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = false, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Car car;
    ...
}

@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
public abstract class Car {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;

    ...
}

@Entity
public class SportsCar extends Car {

    private int hp;

    ...

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "SportsCar [hp=" + hp + ", getId()=" + getId() + "]";
    }
}
```

The test:

```
Garage garage = new Garage();
SportsCar car = new SportsCar();
car.setHp(350);
garage.setCar(car);
em.persist(garage);

...

Garage garage = em.find(Garage.class, garage.getId());
System.out.println(garage.getCar().getClass());
System.out.println(garage.getCar());
System.out.println(garage.getCar() instanceof SportsCar);
```

The above prints:

```
class com.example.Car_$$_jvstd71_f
SportsCar [hp=350, getId()=1]
false
```

Conclusion: Hibernate will create a proxy of the superclass. That proxy will, however, delegate method calls to the subclass instance.